# IE9 with jQuery picture change errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code:

```
<div class="thumbs">                                                    
   <div class="item"><a class="changeImage" data-src="pic_1.jpg" data-id="2"><img src="pic_1.jpg" alt="Karte 2"></a></div>  
   <div class="item"><a class="changeImage" data-src="pic_2.jpg" data-id="3"><img src="pic_2.jpg" alt="Karte 3"></a></div>
   <div class="item"><a class="changeImage" data-src="pic_3.jpg" data-id="4"><img src="pic_3.jpg" alt="Karte 4"></a></div>
   <div class="item active"><a class="changeImage" data-src="pic_4.jpg" data-id="6"><img src="pic_4.jpg" alt="karte 4"></a></div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.changeImage').on("click",function(event){
        if (event.preventDefault) { 
            event.preventDefault();
        } else { 
            event.returnValue = false; 
        }
    var $rel = $(this).data('src');
    var $id = $(this).data('id');
    $(".card img").attr('src', $rel);
    $("input[name=cardid]").val($id);
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    })
})
```

Why is the picture-change not working in IE9? When I switch over to `<a href="pic_1.jpg">` it directly opens the picture in IE9. All other browsers are working fine.

Do you have an ideas?

I am using jQuery 1.9.1

Comment: I switched to jquery 1.7.1 and everything works now. Thanks!

Comment: I believe the problem was actually `$(".card img").attr('src', $rel);`. You should be using `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: Please stop trying to solve browser inconsistencies in your code. That's what jQuery is for. Just call `event.preventDefault();` and that's it. It normalizes the behavior across browsers so that it will stop the default behavior, *so you don't have to* like you're attempting to

Answer (score 0):

Switch to jQuery 1.7.1 helped! They where errors in 1.9.1!

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do in addition to `event.preventDefault()` is `return false` at the very end of a handler, to avoid any cross-browser quirks that might occur.

You may find that the `event.returnValue` is not getting set due to the `if(event.preventDefault)` check returning `true`.

Comment: Please don't listen to this. `return false;` in a jQuery handler is the equivalent of calling both `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()`, so it would be redundant (and unnecessary since you don't want to stop the propagation). Just call whatever you need at the beginning of the handler and stop there...`return false;` usually isn't what you want, and won't execute if your code encounters any exceptions. If you execute the method calls at the beginning, it's more guaranteed to run